# Where is the documentation stating that you cannot remove a parameter from a QT Signal Slot connection if the parameter is not from the end?

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

In the [QT 4.8 documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html) it states that:

> The signals and slots mechanism is type safe: The signature of a signal must match the signature of the receiving slot. (In fact a slot may have a shorter signature than the signal it receives because it can ignore extra arguments.) Since the signatures are compatible, the compiler can help us detect type mismatches.

However code like:

```
QObject::connect(&source, SIGNAL(MySignal(QByteArray,QString,bool), &sink, SLOT(MySlot(QByteArray,bool));
```

gives an "Incompatible sender/receiver arguments" error.

Why is this happening and where is it documented that you have to remove parameters from the end? I understand that with implicit conversions, there may be trouble, but I thought that QT essentially worked with metadata which should be able to hook up a signal/slot as above.

Comment: A bit of a pointless question as it can be easily done with Qt5 connect syntax and a lambda. You are just using the wrong connection method.

Answer (score 3):

> [...] it can ignore extra arguments. [...]

There is no other way than the obvious one to read it.
Admit for a moment that it's technically possible (and it would be a nightmare to do that, trust me) and consider the statement below:

```
QObject::connect(
    &source,
    SIGNAL(MySignal(QString,QString,QString),
    &sink,
    SLOT(MySlot(QString,QString)
);
```

So far, so good. If Qt worked as you described, what's the `QString` to be ignored?
Should you introduce a set of rules and exceptions to treat these cases, so that it quickly leads the signal-slot tool to the hell?

---

That being said, since C++11 we have lambda expressions as part of the language. Qt5 welcomed them and defined a completely new set of `connect` definitions with which you can do exactly what you want. By hand. When you really need it and you know what you are doing. So that the framework must not try to guess out what are your requirements when an event is emitted.

Comment: Thanks, until very recently we weren't in QT5 and C++11. I'm still having trouble using the new QT5 connect calling method (without Lambdas), it's complaining about an "undefined reference" to the staticMetaObject. Note that the old SIGNAL and SLOT based connect works fine in the same place.

Comment: @RobertDuff Probably you haven't derived all the types involved from `QObject`. It isn't easy to say without seeing the real code.

Comment: The class is an interface, but it's derived from QObject (singly no problem of ordering in the base class declarations) and implements the Q_OBJECT macro. The signal and destructor are not pure virtual, but all other methods are.

I unfortunately can't copy and paste code, or even edit the interface I'm using.

Comment: @RobertDuff I don't know how to help you then. Can you create a minimal example to reproduce the error?